# How can I turn on session trace in SQLPLus?

Tags: oracle, trace

I've managed to start SQLPlus and have logged in successfully. I can run queries but I can't trace any of them since when I input `@settrcon` and it gives me the error `SP2-0310: unable to open file "settrcon.sql"` so it means I have to navigate to the directory where this settrcon is so I can trace but I have no idea where it is. The settrcon is meant to alter the session because I need to be able to generate tracefiles.

Comment: I'm sure there is a utility to `find` a misplaced file. Are you sure you have it? I don't think that file is part of SQLPlus.

Comment: if settrcon.sql is your orgnaization own - then check in your server .profile where you can find the location of that file.

Answer (score 1):

`settrcon.sql` is just some custom script that is not part of a standard installation. Wherever you found the reference for it, you may find more information about it there. We can not help with that.

There are multiple ways for enabling taacing:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof

Below examples are from the above link:

```
-- Oracle 10g
SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_enable;
SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_enable(waits=>TRUE, binds=>FALSE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_disable;

SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_enable(session_id=>1234, serial_num=>1234);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_enable(session_id =>1234, serial_num=>1234, waits=>TRUE, binds=>FALSE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_disable(session_id=>1234, serial_num=>1234);

SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.client_id_trace_enable(client_id=>'tim_hall');
SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.client_id_trace_enable(client_id=>'tim_hall', waits=>TRUE, binds=>FALSE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.client_id_trace_disable(client_id=>'tim_hall');

SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.serv_mod_act_trace_enable(service_name=>'db10g', module_name=>'test_api', action_name=>'running');
SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.serv_mod_act_trace_enable(service_name=>'db10g', module_name=>'test_api', action_name=>'running', -
> waits=>TRUE, binds=>FALSE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.serv_mod_act_trace_disable(service_name=>'db10g', module_name=>'test_api', action_name=>'running');

-- All versions.
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET sql_trace=TRUE;
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET sql_trace=FALSE;

SQL> EXEC DBMS_SESSION.set_sql_trace(sql_trace => TRUE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SESSION.set_sql_trace(sql_trace => FALSE);

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 8';
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context off';

SQL> EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_sql_trace_in_session(sid=>123, serial#=>1234, sql_trace=>TRUE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_sql_trace_in_session(sid=>123, serial#=>1234, sql_trace=>FALSE);

SQL> EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_ev(si=>123, se=>1234, ev=>10046, le=>8, nm=>'');
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_ev(si=>123, se=>1234, ev=>10046, le=>0, nm=>'');

-- Available from SQL*Plus since 8i (commandline utility prior to this.
SQL> CONN sys/password AS SYSDBA;  -- User must have SYSDBA.
SQL> ORADEBUG SETMYPID;            -- Debug current session.
SQL> ORADEBUG SETOSPID 1234;       -- Debug session with the specified OS process.
SQL> ORADEBUG SETORAPID 123456;    -- Debug session with the specified Oracle process ID.

SQL> ORADEBUG EVENT 10046 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 12;
SQL> ORADEBUG TRACEFILE_NAME;      -- Display the current trace file.
SQL> ORADEBUG EVENT 10046 TRACE NAME CONTEXT OFF;
 
-- All versions, requires DBMS_SUPPORT package to be loaded.
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SUPPORT.start_trace(waits=>TRUE, binds=>FALSE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SUPPORT.stop_trace;

SQL> EXEC DBMS_SUPPORT.start_trace_in_session(sid=>123, serial=>1234, waits=>TRUE, binds=>FALSE);
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SUPPORT.stop_trace_in_session(sid=>123, serial=>1234);
```